# Name mangling when using @property in Python

Tags: python, name-mangling

I'vo got following code:

```
class Prop:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    @property
    def number(self):
        print("Get number...")
        return self.__number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, number):
        if number == 0:
            print("Setting: 0")
            self.__number = 0
        elif 20 > number > 10:
            print("Setting: 15")
            self.__number = 15
        else:
            print("Setting 5")
            self.__number = 5

    def nr(self):
        print(self.number)


def main():
    p = Prop(200)
    print(p.number)
    p.nr()
    print(p._Prop__number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And to bo honest I don't understand how it works that `self.__number` in getter and setter is the same variable as in `__init__`. As I understand all `__number` will be changed to `_Prop__number`, so it is not the same thing as `self.number` (which name is not changed). When I change `self.number` in `__init__` to `self.__number` (with changing getter and setter name) it's not working at all in the same manner. What's the mechanism behind that?

------ EDIT -------

Ok. I should probably ask question in different way. The correct one - why is it working? I mean - all `__number` are changed to `_Prop__number` and `number` in `__init__` not (so, at the end it will have different name), but it is still the same variable (isn't it?) changed by setter/getter.

What I ment about changing all number to `__number` (in `__init__` and in setter/getter name) is:

```
class Prop:
    def __init__(self, __number):
        self.__number = __number

    @property
    def __number(self):
        print("Get number...")
        return self.__number

    @__number.setter
    def __number(self, __number):
        if __number == 0:
            print("Setting: 0")
            self.__number = 0
        elif 20 > __number > 10:
            print("Setting: 15")
            self.__number = 15
        else:
            print("Setting 5")
            self.__number = 5

    def nr(self):
        print(self.__number)


def main():
    p = Prop(200)
    print(p.__number)
    p.nr()
    print(p._Prop__number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It results with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 27, in main
    p = Prop(200)
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.__number = number
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 20, in __number
    self.__number = 5
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 20, in __number
    self.__number = 5
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 20, in __number
    self.__number = 5
  [Previous line repeated 492 more times]
  File "D:/python/tkinter_tutorial/test/property.py", line 12, in __number
    if __number == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

So I guess it went into infinite loop.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not working at all in the same manner"*? Be specific - what does it do differently?

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. But why do you need to change `self.number` to `self.__number` in `__init__` in the first place?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear. I'm just wondering why is is working when there are different names for the same variable.